# How to have terminal close tab when shell exits?

Tags: terminal, macos

I just recently upgraded from 10.6 to 10.8. On 10.6 I could set the terminal to close the tab/window when the shell exits.

Mountain Lion's terminal just says the process is completed and the tab/window stays open:

```
bash$ exit
logout

[Process completed]
```

I find this very annoying, but I no longer see the preference to change it.
Is there a way to set Mountain Lion's Terminal to close when its process exits?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change this in Terminal's Preferences:

[image]